# How to display multiple NativeScript variables as sentence

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am having an issue displaying multiple NativesScript variables as sentence.

I have 5 variables:

```
string1 = 'Hello';
string2 = 'John'; 
string3 = 'how are you? how are you? how are you?'; 
string4 = 'Button'; 
string5 = 'Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
          Test Test Test Test';
```

I am trying to achieve:

```
Hello John how are you? how are you? how are you? Button Test Test Test 
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
```

string2 and string4 should be clickable. I tried FormattedString with Span but span cannot have any events so it is not clickable. I have also tried GridLayout , but it separate in columns or by rows(where every variable starts in the new line). I also tried StackLayout with horizontal orientation but it didn't wrap properly and didn't go to another line.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edited:**

After help from some other forums I new issue is that using WrapLayout:

```
<GridLayout columns="auto,*,auto"  >
 <Label col="0" text="Testing "></Label>
 <WrapLayout col="1">
  <Label text="Hello"  ></Label>
  <Label text="John"></Label>
  <Label text="how are you? how are you? how are you?"></Label>
  <Label text="Button Button Button"></Label>
  <Label text="Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
      Test Test Test Test Test"></Label>
</WrapLayout>
<Label col="2" text="Test2"></Label>
```

Result:

```
HelloJohn
how are you? how are you? how are you?
Button Button Button
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
```

I want 'how are you? how are you? how are you?' go to line one and 'Test' start in the same line as 'Button' ?

Like this

```
HelloJohnhow are you? how are you? how are you?
Button Button ButtonTest Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
```

Thanks

**Edited:**

I have tried

```
<GridLayout columns="auto,*,auto" class="post-top-wrapper">
 <Label col="0" text="Testing "></Label>
 <FlexboxLayout col="1" flexWrap="wrap">
  <Label text="Hello"  ></Label>
  <Label text="John"></Label>
  <Label text="how are you? how are you? how are you?"></Label>
  <Label text="Button Button Button"></Label>
  <Label text="Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
    Test Test Test Test Test"></Label>
</FlexboxLayout>
<Label col="2" text="Test2"></Label>
```

I get the same result as I mentioned above. There no problem with short strings, but long strings (which doesn't fit in one line) do not start in the same line, but start in the new one.

**Edited:**

I have narrowed the problem: two long strings cannot start in the same line.

Comment: have you tried `<a>` tags?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I don't think you can you use <a> tags in nativeScript, if I am wrong could you please provide the example or the link to it. Thank you

Comment: you cant, i just checked, but you can have labels with tap events

Answer (score 0):

FlexBoxLayout have a way to wrap.

There is also another layout called WrapLayout.

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/layout-containers#wraplayout

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried WrapLayout and FlexboxLayout but every string comes to new line. `<WrapLayout>
  <Label text="Hello"  ></Label>
  <Label text="John"></Label>
  <Label text="how are you? how are you? how are you?"></Label>
  <Label text="Button"></Label>
  <Label text="Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test"></Label>
</WrapLayout>`

Comment: This is guide on how to use flexbox.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You do need to setup the childs and parent properly on flexbox for the wrap to work properly.

Comment: @kivid could you please check my updated question. Thanks